# Mirrored pan/zoom two svg elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to build two force graphs using d3 and make them both zoom/pan at the same time. I'm acheving this by forcing the d3.event.scale() and d3.event.translate() properties from within the zoom event onto the both svgs; the issue is that each svg is somehow saving it's previous translate/scale values when switching from one to another.

i'm using this bit of code from one of d3's examples to make both svgs pan/zoom

```
// Set up zoom support
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", function() { 
            inner.attr("transform", 
                       "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" 
                       + "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); });
svg.call(zoom);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1qja29o/2/

http://www.screencast.com/t/Mtceb6o55XG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was declaring a new zoom handler on every svg.each() pass. I should have declared just one zoom event handler and call that one for every svg.